# How to modify a form action adding the selected radio button value

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, action

I have an HTML form with some radio buttons like these:

```
<form action = "/somecomplicatedurl" method="post">  
   <ul id="category_list">
    <li>
      <label  for="Foo">
      <input type="radio" name="category" id="foo"  value="foo" onclick="this.form.submit()" />
      Foo</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label  for="Bar">
      <input type="radio" name="category" id="bar" value="bar"  onclick="this.form.submit()"/>
      Bar</label>
    </li>              
     <li>
      <label  for="Spam">
      <input type="radio" name="category" id="spam" value="spam"  onclick="this.form.submit()"/>
      Spam</label>
     </li>  
    </ul>
 </form>
```

On the `onclick` event, I would like to add a query string to the action `/somecomplicatedurl` adding the selected category.

For example, clicking the category `spam` should fire an HTTP post with an action like this:

```
/somecomplicatedurl?category=spam
```

Javascript or jQuery are both valid.

**EDIT:**
the category value is already passed correctly to the server; 
I just need that, once the radio button is clicked, the url displayed in the browser address-bar contains the selected category. <sup>*</sup>

<sup>* I would like to avoid to add another redirect because I'm currently handling different cases on that /somecomplicatedurl route</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mixing of POST/GET variables is considered as a poor form. Why not dynamically set a hidden form field:

```
<input type="hidden" id="category" name="category" value="spam" />
```

instead?

Your onclick would become:

```
onClick="document.getElementById('category').value = this.value; this.form.submit();"
```

---

if it's just a display issue, then

```
onclick="this.form.action='/somecomplicatedurl?category=' + this.value; this.form.submit();"
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, misunderstood your question at first.
You can change the form action by adding

```
document.this_form.action = "somecomplicatedurl?category=span";
```

to your onClick-event, before submitting.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that using method "GET" in the form tag would accomplish what you want, or am I misunderstanding the question...

Answer (score 0):

Changing the form method to `get` is probably the easiest, but on the off-chance that it's a little more complicated than that, here's some jQuery. Take out those inline scripts and write something like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#category_list input').change(function () {
        var jQthis = $(this),
            jQform = $(this).parents('form'),
            currentAction = jQform.attr('action'),
            // This removes the current query, if you've added one.
            newAction = currentAction.split('?').shift();

        // Work out the new action and set it.
        newAction += jQthis.val();
        jQform.attr('action', newAction);

        // Submit the form, since your previous handlers were doing that.
        jQform.submit();

    });
});
```